# Cannot find module Ionic TypeScript Atom project

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, atom-editor

Anyone know why I'm getting the two errors below please?

- Cannot find module '`./services/TodosService`'
- Cannot find module '`./objects/todo`'

The component '`my-todos.ts`' is in the highlighted '**Pages**' directory.
The two problematic files are in the '`objects`' and '`services`' directories.

Things I've tried:

- ../../app/
- /
- app/

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you exporting a module from those files?

Comment: Yes I am with export class TodosService ...

Comment: Can you post the import parts from those 2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should've tried this:

```
import {TodosService} from '../../services/TodosService';
```